# Internet Explorer hangs on a XHTML 1.0 Strict validated web page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've developed a web page that displays a huge [Tag Cloud](http://www.gaecupboard.com/tagcloud) and it works pretty smooth in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

Internet Explorer does not seem to digest this page and horribly **HANGS**.
Notes:

1. The page is XHTML 1.0 Strict validated
2. Disabling the Javascripts does not solve the problem
3. Tested on Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702

Should I look to some CSS incompatibility?
Do you have any hints to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**
Following the recommendations of the answerers I have updated the code:
  - Removed the `padding-left` on the `.counter` class
  - Removed the `tag_info` class

You can test it [here](http://1a.gaecupboard.appspot.com/tagcloud).

The problem seems to persist so the question **is still open**.

Comment: This also seems to happen in IE9 when put into IE8 mode (but works fine in normal IE9 mode).

Comment: Just FYI, it also works smoothly in Opera 11.

Comment: I suppose that the high amount of elements might be a huge problem with for IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a CSS issue.  More specifically, the padding-left on the .counter class of screen.css.

Perhaps the internal reflowing of the elements is causing an infinite loop in IE, the design is wrapping the elements quite a bit.

Comment: ahh, beat me by minutes! Out of curiosity - how did you debug this? I'm hoping there is a quicker way than I did!

Comment: ;-) Save source, add <base href="http://www.gaecupboard.com/tagcloud"/> to the top. Divide & conquer the CSS files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).  Once the CSS file has been identified.  Inline it, then Divide & conquer the CSS rules.  If the browser hangs, I can't think of an easier way unfortunately.

Comment: @Lee thanks for the great and precious work, I will try it this evening.

Comment: @Lee, ah that's what I did as well - just slower! Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: @Lee updated the code, it does not seem to solve the problem? Isn't it?

Comment: @systempuntoout: Online it hasn't been changed.  Do you mean locally?

Comment: @Lee nope, check my edit. I've published the modified version with your fix here http://1a.gaecupboard.appspot.com/tagcloud

Comment: @systempuntoout: Ah OK. http://1a.gaecupboard.appspot.com/tagcloud is working on my IE8.  But it *is* very slow.

Comment: @Lee it's incredibly slow, better than my first version though.

Comment: @systempuntoout: I think it's all going to come down to processor speed / memory.

Answer (score 1):

Each tag has the same css class tag_info:

```
<span class="tag_info"><a class="tag_cloud_5" href="/tag/python">python</a><span class="counter">(2,593)</span>&nbsp;</span>
```

A suggestion to make your html "lighter" would be to remove `class="tag_info"`. I was able to remove 70 KB. You are not using this class in your css at the moment.

IE8 still hangs but it takes less time now. Try to simplify your html even more, you should be able to remove `<span class="counter">` too.

A second suggestion would be to break up the tags into multiple pages. Even if you simplify your html enough more tags will be created, the problem will come back and more browsers are going to become a problem.